# Application server libraries not found in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am learning Spring MVC and trying to connect IntelliJ IDEA to Tomcat Server. So far I have downloaded the Tomcat 10 `tar.gz` package from the Tomcat website, extracted and put it at the following location: `/Users/roxhens/Tomcat10`.

Then, I create a new Spring MVC project and go to:

**Add Configuration...** > Click **+** > **Tomcat** **Server** > **Local** and then click **Configure** and provide the **path** above.

When I click **OK**, the following error in the picture shows up: **Cannot Save Settings**.
Where can I find these Application server libraries?

[image: Screenshot from IntelliJ Settings]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.x [doesn't support Tomcat 10 yet](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233724).

Use the supported Tomcat version (9).

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue I guess.. does anyone knows if IntelliJ 2017.2 supports tomcat(9) or not?

Answer (score 5):

If you are **on Windows** and you installed Tomcat on the primary hard drive of your System, **you need to run IntelliJ IDEA as Administrator** to be able to add the Tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

I had this with Apache Tomcat/9.0.76, IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2. I'd first seen "Selected directory is not a valid Tomcat home" and had done:

```
cd /opt/tomcat # or wherever it's installed
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod o+rx {} + # Tomcat dirs available to all users.
```

to make the Tomcat directories usable by all users. I then got "server libraries not found" and fixed it with:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod o+r {} + # Tomcat files readable by all
```

You can keep users from seeing the logs with:

```
sudo chmod -R o-rx logs/
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to point it to $Path/tomcat@9/9.0.45/libexec